# How to align 3 divs inside 1?

Tags: html, css

I want the borders of my divs to look like this

```
                        outer div #info
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 | |-----------------||-----------------||-----------------||
 | |                 ||                 ||                 ||
 | |                 ||                 ||                 ||
 | |                 ||                 ||                 ||
 | |      1 inner    ||      2 inner    ||     3 inner     ||
 | |        div      ||        div      ||       div       ||
 | |                 ||                 ||                 ||
 | |  #leftpannel    ||  #centerpannel  ||  #rightpannel   ||
 | |                 ||                 ||                 ||
 | |                 ||                 ||                 ||
 | |-----------------||-----------------||-----------------||
 |----------------------------------------------------------|
```

but when I put it in a browser it looks like

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 |                    |-----------------||-----------------||
 |                    |                 ||                 ||
 |                    |                 ||                 ||
 |                    |                 ||                 ||
 |                    |      2 inner    ||    3 inner      ||
 |                    |        div      ||      div        ||
 |                    |                 ||                 ||
 |                    |                 ||                 ||
 |                    |                 ||                 ||
 |                    |                 ||                 ||
 |                    |-----------------||-----------------||
 ||------------------|--------------------------------------|
  |                  |                   
  |                  |
  |                  |
  |                  |
  |      1 inner     |
  |        div       |
  |                  |
  |                  |
  |                  |
  |                  |
  |------------------|
```

this is my css

```
#rightpannel
{
   width:32%;
   float:right;
   height:390px;
   border: solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-color:green;
}
#centerpannel
{
    width:32%;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:390px;
    border: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:green;
}
#leftpannel
{
    width:32%;
    float:left;
    height:390px;
    border: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:green;
}
#info
{
    width:92%;
    height:400px;
    border: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:red;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;    
}
```

and this is my html

```
<div id="info">     
    <div id="rightpannel"></div>        
    <div id="centerpannel"></div>       
    <div id="leftpannel"></div> 
</div>
```

I really do not know why this is happening and I appreciate any help
thanks in advance

Comment: Just from a quick glance it is most likely that your info div does not have the proper width to hold the other 3..you have to take into account border widths, margin widths, and the defined width and total it all up to find the correct outer div width.

Comment: I usually use tables to align divs and images and stuff. You could always create one row with three columns. And if you wanted to have a border around the whole table, you could wrap that the table in a div and add a border to that http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Tables to align divs? Never ever ever.

Comment: Sorry for the quick answer before... I put a little more though into it and updated

Comment: Is `#centerpannel {display: inline}` intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of the main div is not great enough to contain the other 3. Padding, margins and borders all need to be accounted for. Set up a fiddle and test but ultimately you'll need to play with the figures to get the desired result.

Also worth lookin up the box model to get a clearer understanding

Never use tables to align divs. that amateur and ugly! Tables are used for tabular data. End.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the css because I think that the margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto in the centerpannel is messing it up is there another way to center the div in the main pannel?

Comment: and what is the problem with using a table to align divs?

Comment: Tables for tabular data. What's the point of using CSS if you're just going to bang divs inside a table an contrain them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#rightpannel {
width:32%;
float:right;
height:390px;
border: solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:green;
margin-left:1%;
}
#centerpannel {
width:32%;
float:right;
height:390px;
border: solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:green;
margin-left:1%;
}
#leftpannel {
width:32%;
float:right;
height:390px;
border: solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:green;
}
#info {
width:100%;
height:400px;
border: solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:red;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UwPjx/)

You still need to change the margins-padding a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things a bit and use one class rather than 3 IDs, but it looks like in order to get the 3 column layout to be "unbreakable" and re-sizable you may need to use a little JavaScript...

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/y9drS/5/)**

HTML

```
<div id="info">
    <div class="pannel"></div>
    <div class="pannel"></div>
    <div class="pannel"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.pannel {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    height:390px;
    border: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:green;
    margin: 2px;
}
#info {
    width:90%;
    height:400px;
    border: solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:red;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:5px 2px 0 2px;
}
```

JS

```
var pannel = function(){
    var x = $('#info').width() / 3 - 6.3;
$('.pannel').width(x);
};

$(document).ready(pannel);
$(window).resize(pannel);
```